# Sublime editor SCSS (SASS) syntax autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, sass, sublimetext3, text-editor, sublime-text-plugin

When I set the syntax to CSS in Sublime Text 3, I get all the properties and values with the autocomplete. For example, if I enter "fl", the autocomplete suggests me "float", and when I press tab, it writes "float:". Then, when I press space, the autocomplete suggests me its values: left, right, etc. But with the SCSS syntax this doesn't happen: the values I got are html, body, section, nav, article, etc, etc.

The packages I have installed are:

- CSS Extended Completions
- Emmet
- Emmet CSS Snipet
- Sublime CodeIntel
- Syntax Highlighting for sass
- SASS
- SCSS

I tried enable and disable different packages, searched for hours and tried many solutions, but nothing fixed the issue. Is there a way to show css values when using SCSS syntax? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [CSS Extended Completions](https://github.com/subhaze/CSS-Extended)

### installation instructions (sublime v3):

1. make sure you can install packages ([instructions](https://packagecontrol.io/installation))
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
3. type: "install" and select `install package`
4. type: `CSS Extended Completions` and select it